# I get permission error, when updating blade file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have this odd error that only happens when I try to upload a new blade,
or update an already working blade file.

The error I get I've tried to remedy by trying to use chmod 777, but I'm to believe there is something with the actual blade file (not the code)
In short, I get this error:

[image]

**So the odd thing is that the current project loads fine with each blade, but as soon as I make a change (or try to create a new blade) it gets this error.**

I did see that there was a discrepancy in the file encoding but have changed that part now.

I tried to be specific on a fuzzy issue that I can't really get my head around

Edit:
Actual error message:
" UnexpectedValueException
The stream or file "/var/www/html/nu_web/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied"

Comment: Don't provide textual error messages as images. [Edit] the question and show it as searchable, copyable, text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using CentOS 7, it could also be SELinux that makes it impossible to write to the log file.

If you have SELinux installed, you may want to know whether SELinux is on and which mode it is in. It is pretty straightforward.
Run the following command to check the current status & mode of SELinux:

```
$ sestatus
```

You can run the following command to set SELinux to permissive mode temporarily:

```
$ sudo setenforce 0
```

You may permanently disable SELinux on CentOS 7 if you want.

Run the following command to edit /etc/selinux/config SELinux configuration file:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/selinux/config
```

Now change **SELINUX=enforcing** to **SELINUX=disabled**

Now reboot your computer with the following command:

```
$ sudo reboot
```

Comment: Yes this did the trick. Works well now. So in other words this was enabled somehow somewhere, but now disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
sudo chmod -R 664 storage
sudo chmod -R 664 bootstrap/cache
```

in the route folder of your application, this will allow for errors to be added to the log file.

Comment: 664 might be better. The files should not need to be executed.

Answer (score -1):

Run in your terminal

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/your_project name
```